# Use multiple OR with one AND

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use multiple OR with one AND operator, but in this example I get error even when I fill `#ads-estate-age`.

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  if ($('#ads-subsubcategory').val() == 92 || $('#ads-subsubcategory').val() == 103 || $('#ads-subsubcategory').val() == 97 || $('#ads-subsubcategory').val() == 100 && $('#ads-estate-age').val().length <= 0) {
    alert('its empty');
  } else {
    alert('ok');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ads-subsubcategory" value="92" />
<input type="text" id="ads-estate-age" />

<a>check</a>
```

I tried to add parentheses but still not working:

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  if (($('#ads-subsubcategory').val() == 92) || ($('#ads-subsubcategory').val() == 103) || ($('#ads-subsubcategory').val() == 97) || ($('#ads-subsubcategory').val() == 100) && $('#ads-estate-age').val().length <= 0) {
    alert('its empty');
  } else {
    alert('ok');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ads-subsubcategory" value="92" />
<input type="text" id="ads-estate-age" />

<a>check</a>
```

What I have missed?

Comment: `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so you need to parenthesize accordingly. It's analogous to the way `*` and `+` work. `a + b * c` means `a + (b * c)`, and similarly `a || b && c` means `a || (b && c)`

Comment: Side note; store the lookup that you are doing 4 times in a variable and reuse that variable.

Comment: @Taplar Better yet, use Array.includes

Comment: True.  Either way, it's good practice to not repeat lookups, :)

Comment: Every hear of the acronym BODMAS https://www.skillsyouneed.com/num/bodmas.html in maths. Similar stuff goes on with operator precedence too.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence - Logic gates are also worth getting your head around http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/CAL/digital-logic/gatesfunc/index.html#logicgates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixing OR and AND without parentheses is always going to produce wonky results.

In your case, you need to add parentheses around the OR blocks, like so:

```
if ((optional || optional2 || optional3) && required) {
    //...
}
```

As it turns out, though, your condition can be rewritten - and in the process greatly simplified to avoid repeition - so parentheses aren't necessary.

```
let
subcat = $('#ads-subsubcategory').val(),
age = $('#ads-estate-age').val();
if ([92, 103, 97, 100].includes(subcat) && age.length === 0) {
    //...
}
```

Note `=== 0` as opposed to `<= 0`; a string cannot logically have length of less than zero.

Answer (score 0):

1.(ads-subsubcategory=92||103|| 97|| 100 && ads-estate-age.length<=0) for false condition.

2.(ads-subsubcategory=true|| false) always true if all and one condition true and if all condition false then condition false.

3.(ads-estate-age.length<=0) true or false.

4(ads-subsubcategory=true && ads-estate-age.length=false) then false.

5.(ads-subsubcategory=false && ads-estate-age.length=false) then false.

6.(ads-subsubcategory=true && ads-estate-age.length=true) then true.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('button').click(function() {
if (($('#ads-subsubcategory').val() == 92) || ($('#ads-subsubcategory').val() == 103) ||($('#ads-subsubcategory').val() == 97) || ($('#ads-subsubcategory').val() == 100) && $('#ads-estate-age').val().length <= 0) 
{
alert('its empty');
} else {
alert('ok');
}
});
});

<input type="text" id="ads-subsubcategory" value="92" />
<input type="text" id="ads-estate-age" />
<button>check</button>
```